# How to generate getters and setters in vscode for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any extension or trick to speed up the development process by adding autogenerate getters and setters methods in VSCODE for FLUTTER?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using [Dart Getters And Setters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterHdd.dartgettersetter) extension to Automatically Generate Getters And Setters.

Comment: Thank you so much this answer will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a model class from [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) site.

Comment: Is there a way to create just getters and setters. I do not want a build a model for JSON response.

Comment: This also will help me to generate a model. I am new here to flutter and just identified a good way to build a model according to JSON response. Thank for your reply.